# Access to user name in config file for Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, configuration, elfinder

I'm using [FMElfinder](https://github.com/helios-ag/FMElfinderBundle) in association with TinyMCE for managing the assets  (images, pdf ...) of the users (managed with FOSUSerBundle)

I've seen that this tool can handle [multiple root](https://github.com/helios-ag/FMElfinderBundle#use-multiple-upload-folder-by-instance) folder, but in my case, it isn't quite usable : i would like to have a root folder for each user.

In the configuration file app/config/config.yml, there is the root path(s) defined :

```
fm_elfinder:
    instances:
        default:
            locale: %locale% 
            ...
            connector:
                roots:
                    uploads:
                        driver: LocalFileSystem
                        path: uploads/data
```

I was thining about "simply" changing the path to something like :

```
path: uploads/data/{the_username}
```

where the username would be the username of the currently logged user

In a controller i can do

```
$user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();
$username = $user->getUsername();
```

But **i don't know if it's possible (and if so, how) to access specifically the username of the logged user into a config file**

Thank you if you have any suggestion

=================[EDIT] ==========================================

I've use the [override of configuration](https://github.com/helios-ag/FMElfinderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/advanced-configuration.md#custom-configuration-provider). I think i followed the steps, but i haven't managed to make it work :

1 - Create the class

```
use FM\ElfinderBundle\Model\ElFinderConfigurationProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
class ElfinderConfigurator implements ElFinderConfigurationProviderInterface
{
    protected $container;
    protected $options;

    /**
     * @param ContainerInterface                             $container
     */
    public function __construct($options, ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container    = $container;
        $this->storage      = $container->get('security.token_storage');
        $this->options      = $options;
    }

    /**
     * @param $instance
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getConfiguration($instance)
    {
        //retrieve basepath
        $basepath_abs = $this->container->get('kernel')->getRootDir()."/../web/uploads";
        $basepath = "uploads/data";

        //define path for user
        $userid = $this->storage->getToken()->getUser()->getId();
        $root = $basepath.'/'.$userid;
        $this->options['instances']['default']['connector']['roots']['uploads']['path'] = $root.'/root';
        $this->options['instances']['default']['connector']['roots']['uploads']['upload_max_size'] = '2M';
        $option = [
            'corsSupport' => false,
            'roots' => $this->options['instances']['default']['connector']['roots'],
        ];

        $root_abs = $basepath_abs.'/data/'.$userid;
        //creates dir if not available
        if (!is_dir($root_abs)) {
            mkdir($root_abs.'/root', 0775, true);
        }

        return $option;
    }
}
```

2 - Set my service :

```
myvendor.mybundle.elfinder_configurator:
    class:        Myvendor\Mybundle\Services\ElfinderConfigurator
    arguments:    ["%fm_elfinder%", "@service_container"]
```

3 - Call the service in app/config/config.yml

```
fm_elfinder:
    configuration_provider: myvendor.mybundle.elfinder_configurator
    ...
```

It works partially : When i open the elfinde, the directory are correctly created if they don't exists. But there must be **a path problem**, and i'm not sure it's **well overriden** because : 
- The thumbs are not displayed in elfinder
- When i add the image to the editor, i don't have the correct path of the image, i have :

```
//app_dev.php/efconnect?cmd=file&target=l1_Q2FwdHVyZSBkJ8OpY3JhbiBkZSAyMDE2LTAxLTI0IDE0OjM2OjI0LnBuZw
```

instead of the actual path of the image (if i don't use the override, the tool works and gives me this path)

```
../../../../uploads/data/1/root/img1.png
```

and no image is displayed.

Also, if i look in the js console for the

```
efconnect?cmd=open&target=&init=1&tree=1&_=1469377765664
```

I see that uplMaxSize is 200M,

[image]

**in any case, there is no js error in the console**

Comment: No this is not possible since the config is used to compile the container which is used by ALL users long before any security component has bound a logged in user.

Comment: @pbenard What form?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for a custom config provider:
https://github.com/helios-ag/FMElfinderBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/advanced-configuration.md#custom-configuration-provider

You could then inject the token storage into the service and fetch the user from
like in any controller:

```
services:
  my_elfinder_configurator:
    class:        Acme\DemoBundle\elFinder\UserAwareConfigurator
    arguments:    ["@token_storage", "%any_container_params%"]
```

Comment: Sorry for the long delay :) I edited my answer with your suggestion. I'm getting close, but wether there is a wrong setting (path or else), or this can't be achieved by the bundle. There is no js error, but the images are not set correctly.